# How to correctly parse base URL from HTTP header?

Tags: parsing, http-headers, base-url

According to [HTML and URLs](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970917/htmlweb.html):

> The base URL can be given by an HTTP header (see [RFC2068]).

The header I receive is:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Tue, 23 Jan 2018 14:12:27 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/5.4.16
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.16
Location: https://www.meetangee.com/
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Is the base URL the URL specified by the `Location` header? If so, should I just parse the characters after `Location:` until end of line, or is there an even simpler way how to get the base URL?

EDIT: Answers to [Is there an HTTP header to say what base URL to use for relative links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157983/) are contrary to the reference I linked, so if it's correct (which I don't assume), then I would expect some source that the reference I linked is incorrect.

Comment: There's no HTTP header for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157983/is-there-an-http-header-to-say-what-base-url-to-use-for-relative-links

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an HTTP header to say what base URL to use for relative links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157983/is-there-an-http-header-to-say-what-base-url-to-use-for-relative-links)

Comment: I added an answer to that question, but in a nutshell, "*The base URL can be given by an HTTP header (see [RFC2068])*" is no longer true. RFC 2068 defined `Content-Base` and `Content-Location` for the purpose of specifying a base URL. RFC 2068 is obsolete, replaced by RFC 2616, which has removed `Content-Base` completely but kept `Content-Location` and its base URL behavior. However, RFC 2616 is also now obsolete, replaced by RFCs 7230-7235, and RFC 7231 redefines `Content-Location`, including to remove its ability to specify a base URL.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The base URL can be given by an HTTP header (see [RFC2068]).

That is true up to and including [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616), but is no longer true starting with [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231).  See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48409040/65863) to [Is there an HTTP header to say what base URL to use for relative links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157983/) for details.

> Is the base URL the URL specified by the `Location` header?

No.  The `Location` header is used for a `3xx` redirect instead.  A User-Agent is meant to follow the redirect by sending a new request to the specified URL.  Some redirects are temporary, in that the original URL should continue being used for future requests of the same entity.  Some redirects are permanent, in that the original URL should no longer be used, replaced with the new URL.

> If so, should I just parse the characters after `Location:` until end of line, or is there an even simpler way how to get the base URL?

An entity's base URL is the final non-redirect URL used to request the entity, unless specified otherwise by the entity itself (such as in a `<base>` element in HTML).