# Make an href/src relative to the document, not its containing "directory"

Tags: html, src

Say I'm serving two files:

- `http://example.com${ROOT}/`
- `http://example.com${ROOT}/js/stuff.js`

Where `${ROOT}` can be any prefix including an empty string. Now I want to make the first file be an HTML page that uses the second:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/stuff.js"></script>
  </head>
  ...
</html>
```

The above works if and only if `${ROOT}` is `""`. If however it is something like `"/foo/bar"` then the script tags tries to load `http://example.com/foo/js/stuff.js` (note the missing `/bar`). If I then set `src` to `"../bar/js/stuff.js"` it then only works for `${ROOT}` ending in `".../bar"`.

If I know in advance what `${ROOT}` will be, I can adjust the `<script>` tag, but in my case, I'm strongly motivated to make it be totally static well before I can know `${ROOT}` (I'm more or less serving directly out of a read-only file system).

Things I've looked at that don't seem to work:

- Different forms of links (`js/stuff.js`, `./js/stuff.js`, `/js/stuff.js`, etc.) all go the wrong places in at least one case.
- The `<base href="..." />` tag doesn't work for the same reason as `<script>` not working; it would require knowing `${ROOT}` when the tag is generated.
- [The HTTP `Content-Base` and `Content-Location` headers are obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157983/is-there-an-http-header-to-say-what-base-url-to-use-for-relative-links/48409040#48409040).

---

The only thing that seems to be a possibility (but rather gross) is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  const dom = document.createElement("script");
  const t = document.location.origin + 
            document.location.pathname +
            "/js/stuff.js";
  dom.setAttribute('src', t);
  dom.onload = function() { Go(); };  // must be differed till tag loads. 
  document.head.appendChild(dom);
</script>
```